# Do these pictures suggest mold is growing behind walls?

Tags: mold

Seeking advise on mold.

1. This wall isn’t hard, feels kind of soft to knock.  Do u know what material it is and can mold hi through it?
2. You can see in the pics I peeled it and it just revealed more mold.  From the pics can u tell if this suggests the mold is growing behind the walls?
3. I cleaned the area with vinegar and covered it in foil paper.  It seems the covering reduced the mold smell.  If so would this suggest it is coming through the walls? Note I could be wrong about this as the vinegar may be masking the mold smell but if u can answer I’ll know the situation when the vinegar dissipates.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Guys, just to add should I keep peeling them if it shows more and more mold?

Comment: We can not say about what is in the wall without seeing in the wall, seems probable if it is soft,  but there is surface mold visible in the photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.   But maybe.   You would be surprised how easy mold grows on the surface of a wall - especially sheetrock.   It certainly looks like there was/is some offset moisture from those pipes which looks like it has dried up.

While there is mold on the wall it isn't even that bad on this side which means it could be worse on the other side but me guesses that the water is from the pipes... not the other side.   So I would just scrape off the mold (sure hit it with bleach or whatever).   This is a good area that makes a point to use an oil based paint.

Probably the best thing to do is clean the area up, get the mold off and then check it every day or two.   There is no reason to open up the wall unless you can verify that the wall has remained dry, on your side and the mold progresses to grow more.

Answer (score 0):

Vinegar will kill mold but it stinks,
hydrogen peroxide will also kill mold and it doesn’t stink.
Is there a concrete wall behind the Sheetrock ?
Concrete walls can be a source of moisture.

Moisture  and sheetrock equals mold believe me I live in Oregon we know mold and slugs.
If you are concerned get a dehumidifier in there to help dry things out remove the moisture and the mold will go dormant.
The additional positive about hydrogen peroxide it will bleach the mold especially at higher concentrations +7-12% range will turn blue jeans into painters whites ok I never spilled that much but it will take the color out of fabric.

Once the mold is taken care of and the sheet rock is dried it needs to be painted a good oil based primer is what I use you need to remove the loose paint for best long term results.

If moisture is entering from outside the moisture needs to be stopped or this problem will get worse. In any case the source needs to be stopped.

Just a note, some folks think all molds are bad, there are only a few toxic ones but they do indicate moisture problems.

It appears that the Sheetrock paper has been removed in a small section Use caution there because this paper is part of the strength.
Peal the loose paint, kill the mold , dry the area ( dehumidifier & fan) , I would get some white wall paper  and repair the missing paper area , when dry and sanded prime and paint.